# How Can I send Clients value in ASP.NET Controller?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, signalr

I have written a code in c#, javascript, using client library SignalR to refresh a page in database value change. My code is

```
<form asp-action="Start" method="post" class="form-stacked">
    <button type="submit" id="startPractice" class="button-primary">Start Practice</button>
</form>

<script src="~/js/ignalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/chat.js"></script>
```

My API method is which is called while clicking start practice is

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(long sessionId)
{
     // Database change logic

     SignalRClientHub sr = new SignalRClientHub();
     await sr.SendMessage();

     // Rest of the logic

     return this.View();
}
```

```
 public class SignalRClientHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendMessage(string user = null, string message = null)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }
    }
```

code of chat.js

```
"use strict";

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/SignalRClient").build();

connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
    location.reload();
});
```

When I click the button start practice it hits SendMessage Method, but I got an error

```
object reference not set to an instance
```

because the value of the Client was null. How Can I fix this?

Comment: Your Clients is probably null : await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);

Comment: What line results in the nullreference error?

Comment: @Devilscomrade at await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message); this line I am getting an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** new up a hub manually. In order to send to clients from outside of the hub you need to use the `IHubContext<THub>`. See the docs for details https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: The Clients value is not null now thanks for that. Now In SignalRClientHub class, I have written a code so that it calls the 

```
connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
    location.reload();
});
```
the above method of chat.js and I want the location to be reloaded, but I cannot go to that method of chat.js, I tried console.log instead of the location.reload, but that method was no called by the Hub. Can you help to get hit into that method of chat.js?

Comment: Did you start the client? In your pasted code you haven't started the client yet.

Comment: How Can I start the Client?

Comment: You should really read the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Thanks a lot I was not missing a connection start it worked. I have another issue if you could help it would be great. Every page is reloading fine, but I don't want to reload the tab from which API is called, How Can I do that?